# Properties of orthogonal vectors and pi/4

Tags: linear-algebra

Why is true that the addition of two orthogonal vectors with the same magnitude makes an angle of  pi/ 4  radians with both vectors.

A diagram would help.

This is in context of freshman linear algebra.

Comment: The given vectors form a square, their sum is the diagonal of such square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume without loss of generality that the orthogonal vectors say $v,w$ in a space with an inner product are unit vectors then
$$\frac{\langle v+w,w\rangle}{\sqrt{\langle v+w,v+w\rangle}}=\frac{\langle w,w\rangle}{\sqrt{\langle v,v\rangle+\langle w,w\rangle}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
and $\arccos(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})=\frac{\pi}{4}$.